is it possible to attach an excel file to an answer?
Is it possible to attach an excel file to an answer?
Or to a question too, for that matter.
For example , for questions that are related to numerical calculations.

You can link to a file you've uploaded somewhere else but I would be hesitant to open such a file. Another option could be to share a link to an online spreadsheet tool but that has the drawback of making the answer depend on an external resource that can go away or changed.
A good answer should stand on its own.
